# Use Html.DisplayFor in custom HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a custom HtmlHelper extension and I need to use Html.DisplayFor inside this helper. How is it possible to use it like in a view?

I have entities, all of them inherit from BaseEntity which has Id, CreatedOn etc...

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Created On"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Updated On"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Helper:

```
public static class InfoExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString Info(this HtmlHelper helper, BaseEntity m)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append($"{Html.DisplayNameFor(m.CreatedOn)}: {Html.DisplayFor(m.CreatedOn)}");
        sb.Append($"{Html.DisplayNameFor(m.UpdatedOn)}: {Html.DisplayFor(m.UpdatedOn)}");

        return new HtmlString(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

I'm trying to output a html result like:

```
Created On: 15.04.2017 13:28
Updated On: 18.04.2017 15:36
```

Comment: `helper.DisplayFor()` but what is `CreatedOn` and what is `BaseEntity`? And how are you using this in the view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Updated with required details

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the inbuilt `HtmlHelper` methods (note you need to include `using System.Web.Mvc.Html;`)

```
public static MvcHtmlString InfoFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    TagBuilder bold = new TagBuilder("b");
    bold.InnerHtml = helper.DisplayNameFor(expression);
    html.Append(bold);
    html.Append(helper.DisplayFor(expression));
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
}
```

And in the view

```
@Html.InfoFor(m => m.CreatedOn)
```

Comment: helper.DisplayNameFor and DisplayFor is not available.

Comment: Ok, the problem was relating to using Antlr.Runtime.Misc for Func. I've changed it to using System and now I see there isn't a problem.